# How to write code to delete customer group and assign the customers in it to default customer group?

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I have created Customer group using InstallData.php in

> app/code/Mymodule/setup

I need to delete it programatically.How should I do it?
I added UpgradeData.php inside Setup folder.

```
<?php

namespace <Mymodule\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<=')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->query("DELETE FROM customer_group WHERE customer_group_id = '4'");
      //  $sql = "Delete FROM " . $tableName." Where emp_id = 10";
//$connection->query($sql);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

But it is not working.Help me out.

Comment: Please check my answer and don't forget to remove your module entry from setup_module table.

Comment: Is it working for you or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to remove customer group using upgradeData script:

```
<?php
namespace YourCompany\YourPackage\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $groupFactory;

    public function __construct(GroupFactory $groupFactory) {
        $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<=')) {
            // remove customer group
            /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $group */
            $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
            $group->load(4)
                ->delete();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

You can add another script to assign required customers to default group :)

To update customers group:

create a file with any name like AssignToDefault.php with below code

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$productionDomains = '';
$developmentDomains = '';
$i = 0;
$customers = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($customers as $record) {
    $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($record->getId());
    $customer->setGroupId(1);
    $customer->save();
}
echo "<br />" . "All Customers Updated successfully!";
?>
```

Put this file under MagentoRootDirectory/pub folder and execute below command in terminal:

```
php pub/AssignToDefault.php
```

here AssignToDefault.php  is the filename in which we added the code to update customer group. I didn't check but you can give a try to this code, I hope it would be working fine. Please let me know if you find any issue..

Comment: ..I will try this immediately and inform you.Please wait..

Comment: I tried.but it doesnot get deleted.What to do?Where can I check?@Himmat Paliwal

Comment: Have you updated YourCompany\YourPackage in class naming?

Comment: Could you check your custom module version in database under setup_module table? If it is already 1.0.1 then try to update the next one i.e. 1.0.2 in module.xml and also update the code to check module version 1.0.2 in upgradeData script.. try with it and let me know in case any issue..

Comment: Have you checked the module version in database?

Comment: It is 0.0.1.I changed it to 1.0.2 and performing deploy now

Comment: Perfectly deleted...Cheers...@Himmat paliwal.Can you please tell me how to move customers  under this Customer group to default customer group?

Comment: See my updated answer @Vishal Mariappan, please accept it as an answer if it worked.

Comment: @Vishal Mariappan Did you get chance to check the updated answer?

Answer (score 2):

We should use GroupRepositoryInterface.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $groupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepositoryInterface) {
        $this->groupRepo = $groupRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<=')) {
            $groupId = 5;
            $this->groupRepo->deleteById($groupId);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from admin but if you want to do this from code then you need to call GroupRepository's deleteById function for this.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepository $groupRepository)
{
    $this->groupRepo = $groupRepository
}

public function upgrade()
{
   $setup->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<=')) {
         $groupId = 5;
         $this->groupRepo->deleteById($groupId)
    }

    $setup->endSetup();

}
```

Please don't forget to update  setup_version to 1.0.1 in module.xml file and run setup upgrade. Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Where should I place this file?What is the name of file?Can you please provide me the path

Comment: You can try this in upgrade data file.

Comment: Okay wait please..@Ramkishan

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any code for delete `customer group` programmatically,

Just delete `customer group` from the admin side and all customer which consider that group will automatically be assigned into default `general group`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ya.I know that.But I want my code to do that.@Hit's Can you help me?

Comment: Yes sure just try with @Himmat's answer maybe your problem solve else I will try

Answer (score 0):

Create File in **VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer Group Factory Model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory
     */
    protected $groupFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory
    ) {
        $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $group */

        $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
        $group->load(customer_group_id);
        $group->delete();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

It will run when you upgrade setup.